# Array populate missing index

Tags: php, arrays

Have a code that display array with same eid inside it have an array of days

```
foreach ($data['display'] as $item) {
             $eid = implode($data['data'][$i]['eid']);
            $date = date('Y-m',strtotime($item['date_d'][0]));
            if (!isset($groups[$eid])) {
                $groups[$eid] = array(
                    'employeeId' => $eid,
                    'efullname' => $item['fullname'][0],
                    'hrsdiff' => $item['hrsdiff'][0],
                    'days' => array(
                        $date => $item['key'][0],
                    )
                );
            } else {
                @$groups[$eid]['days'][$date] += $item['key'][0];
            }
            $i++;
        }
```

that displays:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [employeeId] => 21
            [efullname] => MANOGURA EDGAR
            [hrsdiff] => 2.2331
            [days] => Array
                (
                    [2014-02] => 23
                    [2014-03] => 26
                    [2014-04] => 23
                )

        )

[1] => Array
        (
            [employeeId] => 1
            [efullname] => IBARDOLAZA VIRGILIO
            [hrsdiff] => 5.0333
            [days] => Array
                (
                    [2014-01] => 2
                    [2014-02] => 24
                    [2014-03] => 26
                    [2014-04] => 26
                )

        )
```

want to have the days array to have same index if missing it will add the missing index days and the value must be 0 ex in index[0] the days array should have [2014-01] => 0

Comment: provide your code, what you tried

Comment: @prava see code above already posted

Comment: I think it might help you provided an example output/structure of what you want to achieve.

Comment: check the code, you wrote in else condition `@$groups[$eid]['days'][$date] += $item['key'][0];` - why you added `@` and `+=` symbol, if you want to assign the value for the date key, then you should use like this `$groups[$eid]['days'][$date] = $item['key'][0];`

Comment: @parava if i dont have the += the value will be all 1

Comment: @Havelock can you help me with this thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming two arrays of which the missing keys could be in either of them:

```
$a = array('2014-02' => 'afoo', '2014-03' => 'abar', '2014-04' => 'abaz');
$b = array('2014-02' => 'bfoo', '2014-03' => 'bbar', '2014-01' => 'bbaz');

$a += array_fill_keys(array_keys(array_diff_key($b, $a)), 0);
$b += array_fill_keys(array_keys(array_diff_key($a, $b)), 0);

print_r($a);
print_r($b);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [2014-02] => afoo
    [2014-03] => abar
    [2014-04] => abaz
    [2014-01] => 0
)
Array
(
    [2014-02] => bfoo
    [2014-03] => bbar
    [2014-01] => bbaz
    [2014-04] => 0
)
```